# How to handle the array of objects in Ember Js Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting the response from the server like

```
category:{
    listOfCategory: [
        "diabetes",
        "general"
    ],
    id:1

}
```

using Ember data findAll method. I'm returning this to my model and I'm trying to display in hbs file using each loop.

js code

```
model(){
       return this.store.findAll('category');
}
```

hbs code

```
{{#each model as |category|}}
     <h1>{{category.listOfCategory}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

Output :

```
diabetes,general
```

I want to display as separate category.

Comment: Please show your model. Maybe consider creating a separate category model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data modify your each loop:

```
{{#each model as |category|}}
 {{#each category.listOfCategory as |cat|}}
  <h1>{{cat}}</h1>
 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Your loop is calling for the array of categories, instead of looping through the category array elements.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors or is the output incorrect?